User defined logvars for Django application deployed on uWSGI server
I have deployed a Django application on a uWSGI server, which has the following middleware
# myapp/middleware.py

from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

class LogUserMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request):
        request.META['REMOTE_USER'] = 'test'

The middleware is added in the settings.py file as well
# myapp/settings.py

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'myapp.middleware.LogUserMiddleware',
    ...
]

Then in the uWSGI config file also the logvar is used
...
log-format = %(ltime) %(addr){uWSGI} : %(method) %(uri) %(status) %(REMOTE_USER)
...

But still the logs show as
19/May/2024:09:01:49 +0000 127.0.0.1{uWSGI} : GET /health_check 200 -

Basically the logvar is getting replaced with - instead of showing test
Is there any extra config to be done?

After doing some research I found that uWSGI don't accept the logvars which are set in the Middleware of the Django application.
To use custom logvars we have to wrap the WSGI Application provided by Django to our custom WSGI Application.
First, create a custom WSGI Application in the wsgi.py file of Django application as
import os
import uwsgi
from datetime import datetime

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'main_folder.settings')


class WSGIApplication:
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = get_wsgi_application()

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        current_time = datetime.now()
        # noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
        uwsgi.set_logvar('REMOTE_USER','test')
        return self.app(environ, start_response)


application = WSGIApplication()

Then in the config file of the uWSGI server make sure the module option is set to application variable of the wsgi.py file as
chdir = /path/to/project
module = main_folder.wsgi:application

then we can use the logvar REMOTE_USER in the log format option of the uWSGI config file as
log-format = %(ltime) %(addr){uWSGI} : %(method) %(uri) %(status) %(REMOTE_USER)

to get proper logs as
19/May/2024:09:01:49 +0000 127.0.0.1{uWSGI} : GET /health_check 200 test

